# Move Elastic IP from one AWS account to another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, transfer, elastic-ip

I have two AWS account and One Elastic IP and all domains and everything connected to via this Elastic Ip but, due to some reason. I want to transfer everything to another account. so I have to transfer Elastic Ip also there is any way?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but I don't think there is any way you can do it yourself - you will need to open a support case and they will do it for you after confirming ownership and approval with the two accounts involved.

Comment: I found this, hope some helps https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=926017&tstart=0